# Selenium: The variables doesn't change even after import changes

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I'm working on a webpage scraping project, using selenium library, in which I need to extract some data out of some tables. As a part of project, I need to iterate the table rows and extract the author of article condition, but it just works for the first row. It seems the variable saves the data of first row and doesn't change, even after each iterating.
This is mentioned part of my code:

```js
div_result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("result-body-paper")
papers = div_result.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
papers_information = []
for paper in papers:
  data = paper.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
  result_title = data[1].text

  author = paper.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-paper-person="{id}"]'.format(id=person_id))
  try:
    first_author = author.find_element_by_tag_name("i").get_attribute("class")
  except:
    first_author = ""
  author_condition = "Helper"
  if first_author != "":
    if "pencil" in first_author:
      author_condition = "First Writer"
    if "asterisk" in first_author:
       author_condition = "Orginal Writer"
    if "star" in first_author:
      author_condition == "Orginal Worker"
  papers_information.append([author_condition,result_title])
```

Unlike what I expect, every time `first_author` and `author` is the same as it was at the first row of table. However, other parts work correctly and operates properly.
Is that bug or something?
By the way, this is the part of html code I'm trying to extract data from (just consists two of table rows):

```html
<tr class="zarEn selectable">
  <td class="result row center" width="35">1</td>
  <td class="result title "><a href="...">Hepatic insulin resistance, metabolic syndrome and cardiovascular disease</a></td>
  <td class="result author zarsmallEn" width="200">
    <span data-paper-person="98155">
      <a href="...">
        <img src="..." class="person-avatar-mini">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil crimson absolute"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td class="result source_title ">
    <a href="...">Clinical Biochemistry</a>
  </td>
  <td class="result source_cs">
    <a href="...">2.35</a>
  </td>
  <td class="result published_year center">2009</td>
  <td class="result citation center">217</td>
</tr>
<tr class="zarEn selectable">
  <td class="result row center">2</td>
  <td class="result title "><a href="...">Molecular and cellular mechanisms linking inflammation to insulin resistance and β-cell dysfunction</a></td>
  <td class="result author zarsmallEn">
    <span data-paper-person="14144442">
      <a href="...">
      <img src="...">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil lightgray absolute"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span data-paper-person="14137800">
      <a href="..."><img src="..."></a>
    </span>
    <span data-paper-person="98155">
      <a href="...">
      <img src="...">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-asterisk crimson absolute"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td class="result source_title ">
     <a href="...">Translational Research</a>
  </td>
  <td class="result source_cs">
    <a href="...">4.26</a>
  </td>
  <td class="result published_year center">2016</td>
  <td class="result citation center">71</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, class name of two "" is different, but `first_author` gets the first one and doesn't change anymore!

Comment: what is the person_id you are giving to the xpath?

Comment: It's a number extracted from the webpage and is unique for every webpage. It's been defined formerly in original code.